# Arduino Step Motor LED remains on

Tags: arduino, stepper

So I am using a Step Motor 28BYJ-48 and while turning the LEDS will light up. Now the problem that I'm having is, that the LED labeled D won't turn off.
My ESP is going into deepsleep to save battery and to improve that, it would be really nice if the LED would be off too.

I am using the CheapStepper library.
When I manually restart the ESP, all LED's are off.

Maybe I have to end the Cheapstepper class or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually, a stepper needs a current to keep its position. And it's a question to the unknown driver electronics.

Comment: if you would care to educate yourself about the working principles of stepper drivers, to read the documentation of CheapStepper and your stepper driver you wouldn't have to ask this question. a stepper is always powered unless you unpower it. then it can be rotated freely which in most scenarios is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leds indicate the polarity of the stepper phases. The only way to turn off all leds is to turn off the motor.

CheapStepper library provides a function for this. `void CheapStepper::off()`